# Perl API for MongoDB (MongoDB::Async) does not have a callback argument?

Tags: mongodb, perl

I want to benchmark MongoDB with perl Async API. (MongoDB::Aysnc). but when I insert 70K times ASYNCHRONOUSLY in a loop, I just receive 30%-40% response against the queries from MongoDB. While MongoDB only inserts 5K times in a second synchronously. Can you please guide me how can i improve the performance.

and Functions provided by MongoDB::Async does not have a callback argument, like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#
# The traditional first program.
# Strict and warnings are recommended.
use strict;
use warnings;
use Benchmark;
use MongoDB::Async;
use MongoDB::Async::Pool;
use Coro;
use EV;
use Coro::EV;
use Coro::AnyEvent;

my $id;
my $pool = MongoDB::Async::Pool->new( { host => 'localhost', port => 27017 }, { timeout => 0, max_conns => 50 } );
my $it   = 10;
my $t0   = Benchmark->new;
my $revents;
# IO

for ( my $i = 0; $i < $it; $i++ ) {
    async {    # parallel query
        $id = $pool->get->mydb->users->insert( { "First_name" => "Talha", "Last_name" => "Umair", "Age" => $i } );    #for insert query uncomment this line
        print "received ($i) $id is \n";
    };
}

my $t1 = Benchmark->new;
my $td = timestr( timediff( $t1, $t0 ) );
print "$it iteration took $td Seconds \n";
EV::loop;        # it stuck in this loop what to do to exit from it.
print "control returned back to MAIN function\n";
```

So, how I can use them? Can anyone give an example?

Thanks In advance

Comment: Re-iterating the comment that was made before this was migrated ( and presumably "back" here, talking benchmarking doesn't help people understand your programming question ). But this library is built on [Coro](https://metacpan.org/pod/Coro) which deliberately tries to "hide" the callback implementation while still processing asynchronously. If you are expecting callbacks or prefer it then look at something like [Mango](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mango) instead

Answer (score 1):

The comment by Neil Lunn said this but I feel like people seeing this in the future need to see something more obvious.  Your question is basically: "How can I use callbacks in MongoDB::Async" and the answer is:

You can't, it does not support them.  As mentioned in that comment, Mango does support them like this:

```
use Mango::Collection;
my $db = Mango->new('mongodb://localhost:27017')->db('test');
my $collection = Mango::Collection->new(db => $db);
for ( my $i = 0; $i < $it; $i++ ) {
    $collection->insert({ "First_name" => "Talha", "Last_name" => "Umair", "Age" => $i } => sub {
      my ($collection, $err, $oid) = @_;
      print "received ($i) $oid is \n";
    });
}
Mojo::IOLoop->start unless Mojo::IOLoop->is_running;
```